# Lua nvim_command highlight not working unless manually run

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following line at the very end of my `init.lua`

```lua
vim.api.nvim_command('hi CursorLineNr guibg=bg')
```

But it doesn't work. When I launch nvim, the CursorLineNr highlight group is still wrong. And yet, when I manually type `:hi CursorLineNr guibg=bg`, it works.

I'm not sure if this has to do with any `Packer` plugins finishing execution after the very last line of my `init.lua` or something?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is "correct", but it worked for me:

```
vim.api.nvim_command[[
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight CocErrorSign guifg=#bf616a
]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to put highlight settings after the colorscheme is set in your init.lua because it resets the highlight.

```
vim.cmd("colorcheme gruvbox")
vim.cmd("hi CursorLineNr guibg=bg")
```

In this order